# Duplicate object cannot be removed in TreeSet

Tags: java, treeset

I have an `Animal` class and `Dog` class, `Dog extends Animal` and I override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the `Animal` class, now I built an `ArrayList<Dog>` and put it in the `TreeSet` object by using `addAll` method, but seems duplicate Dog object cannot be removed. see my code below:

Animal class:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private int age;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Animal animal = (Animal) o;
        System.out.println("equals: " + animal.getName());
        return this.name.equals(animal.getName());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println(name + "'hashCode: " + name.hashCode());
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Dog Class:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

The test method like this:

```
private static <T extends Animal> void testSortandRemoveDuplicateElement(List<T> list) {
    System.out.println("Before sort...");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + ", " + list.get(i).getAge());
    }
    TreeSet<T> set = new TreeSet<T>(new AnimalComparator<T>());
    System.out.println("After sort...");
    set.addAll(list);
    for(T t : set) {
        System.out.println(t.getName() +", " + t.getAge());
    }
}

private static void testDriver1() {
    Dog d1 = new Dog();
    d1.setName("abc");
    d1.setAge(1);

    Dog d2 = new Dog();
    d2.setName("abc");
    d2.setAge(2);

    Dog d3 = new Dog();
    d3.setName("Wxy");
    d3.setAge(0);

    List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    dogList.add(d1);
    dogList.add(d2);
    dogList.add(d3);

    testSortandRemoveDuplicateElement(dogList);
}
```

for debug purpose, I added some print statements in that 2 methods  in the Animal class, but seems they were not be called, I cannot see any output from that 2 methods in the console, can you tell me why, does that mean I have to override that 2 methods in the subclass Dog, Cat and so on? I don't think it's a good way.

Comment: TreeSet doesn't use equals() and hashCode() to compare objects. It uses the AnimalComparator you passed as argument when constructing it. Read the javadoc.

Comment: `TreeSet` doesn't use `equals()` and `hashCode()` but the comparator you passed. After all it is _sorting_ the elements and neither `equals()` nor `hashCode()` provide any information that's useful for sorting.

Comment: Please show the code for `AnimalComparator`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in the comments, the TreeSet uses the comparator you provide it with to compare elements for duplicates.
So if your Comparator returns 0 when the two names are equal, then it should work as you expect.

Example : try using

```java
TreeSet<T> set = new TreeSet<T>(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName));
```

instead of

```java
TreeSet<T> set = new TreeSet<T>(new AnimalComparator<T>());
```

HTH!

Comment: @user2575502 did it help ? If it answered your question, you may want to accept the answer so that other people find their way easier...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your testSortandRemoveDuplicateElement method to the following:

```
private static <T extends Animal> void testSortandRemoveDuplicateElement(List<T> list) {
    System.out.println("Before sort...");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + ", " + list.get(i).getAge());
    }
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>(list);
    Set<T> treeset = new TreeSet<T>(new AnimalComparator<T>());
    treeset.addAll(set);

    System.out.println("After sort...");
    for(T t : set) {
        System.out.println(t.getName() +", " + t.getAge());
    }
}
```

The HashSet will eliminate the 'duplicates' based on the equals and hashcode implementations. Afterwards you can create the TreeSet to sort the remaining elements according to your comparator.

Comment: Why do you need 2 sets?

Comment: You don't 'need' to use 2 sets, there are other ways to solve this use case of course. But for the sake of argument and to show the difference between how a HashSet and TreeSet work I thought I'd use this approach to stay close to the OP's mindset.